# How can I learn to optimize SQL queries

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I know how to write `SQL` queries and can get the results I need. But sometimes my queries are slow and I don't fully understand why.

What are some good resources for learning to write efficient queries and to optimize the queries I've already written?

Comment: What's argumentative about this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be Community wiki, as questions like "Which book is recomment for C?"

Comment: are you mainly interested in SQLServer query optimisation, or optimisation for other DBMSs, too? The techniques tend to vary between dialects of SQL.

Comment: I was looking for advice that is platfrom agnostic. I realize now that there are many optimizations that are platform specific, and I may need to look into the one for my specific platform. But at first, I just wanted learn how I can write well formed queries.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would say the main things are:

- **Understand the set-based nature of SQL** by reading platform-neutral books such as [Celko's](http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celko/e/B000ARBFVQ); this will help you avoid making newbie mistakes, like using cursors (or other iterative approaches) where they are not needed.
- **Learn the basics of normalization** and when to denormalize; efficient queries start with well-organized data.
- **Understand where indexes can be helpful** and where they can't; e.g., grasp how the cardinality of your data affects index efficiency, what SARGable queries are, and when to use multi-column indexes.
- **Learn how to use EXPLAIN PLAN or its equivalent** for your platform; by observing how your query is being compiled and the resources it is consuming, you will better understand the bottlenecks.
- **Learn platform-specific methods** such as indexed/materialized views, full text indexing, and methods for paging and dealing with hierarchical data.

Comment: +1 that covers it fairly well.

Comment: To your point on indexes, i'd add learning what a covering index is. Functional and filtered/partial indexes might also be useful to know about, although they're rather obscure, and not widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL specific information, [chapter 7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html) of the reference manual is all about optimization. § 7.3, in particular, covers [MySQL statement optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/statement-optimization.html). The PostgreSQL wiki similarly documents [optimizing](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) specifically for that RDBMS. Microsoft's "[How To: Optimize SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx)" is retired; I'm not certain if there's a more recent document. Oracle has a couple documents on [query optimization](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/sql_1016.htm) for the various versions.

Answer (score 0):

use indexes where tables can use one, and also run Database Tuning Advisor on a query if you have SQL Server.